# Can't describe a collision between two objects in different class to add a health bar

Tags: c#, object, xna, collision

I'm trying to add a health bar to my 2d platformer. Atm i'm trying to define a collision between two objects (a rocket and the player), but I don't know how to refer/use them. I've written the error as a comment in the code.

This is the health class:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

class Health : GameObjectList
{
public Health(int layer = 3, string id = "") : base(layer, id) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 255; i+=85)
        if(i % 85 == 0)
        {
            SpriteGameObject health = new SpriteGameObject("Sprites/spr_health", 3);
            health.Position = new Vector2(120 + i, 15);
            this.Add(health);
        }
}

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);
    Player player = GameWorld.Find("player") as Player;
    Rocket rocket = GameWorld.Find("rocket") as Rocket;

    foreach (GameObject obj in gameObjects)
    {
        SpriteGameObject h = obj as SpriteGameObject;
        if (rocket.CollidesWith(player))
            //This is wat it says as an error:
            //An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TickTick.exe
            //Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        {
            this.Remove(h);
            return;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I've used the same GameWorld.find method in the rocket class when there was no health bar and that worked:

```
public void CheckPlayerCollision()
{
    Player player = GameWorld.Find("player") as Player;
    if (this.CollidesWith(player) && this.Visible)
        player.Die(false);
    // CURRENTLY DON'T WANT THIS TO HAPPEN BECAUSE OF HEALTH BAR
}
```

This is the GameWorld Find method:

```
public GameObject Find(string id)
{
    foreach (GameObject obj in gameObjects)
    {
        if (obj.ID == id)
            return obj;
        if (obj is GameObjectList)
        {
            GameObjectList objlist = obj as GameObjectList;
            GameObject subobj = objlist.Find(id);
            if (subobj != null)
                return subobj;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Rocket class:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

class Rocket : AnimatedGameObject
{
protected double spawnTime;
protected Vector2 startPosition;

public Rocket(bool moveToLeft, Vector2 startPosition)
{
    this.LoadAnimation("Sprites/Rocket/spr_rocket@3", "default", true, 0.2f);
    this.PlayAnimation("default");
    this.Mirror = moveToLeft;
    this.startPosition = startPosition;
    Reset();
}

public override void Reset()
{
    this.Visible = false;
    this.position = startPosition;
    this.velocity = Vector2.Zero;
    this.spawnTime = GameEnvironment.Random.NextDouble() * 5;
}

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);
    if (spawnTime > 0)
    {
        spawnTime -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        return;
    }
    this.Visible = true;
    this.velocity.X = 600;
    if (Mirror)
        this.velocity.X *= -1f;
    CheckPlayerCollision();
    // check if we are outside the screen
    Rectangle screenBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, GameEnvironment.Screen.X, GameEnvironment.Screen.Y);
    if (!screenBox.Intersects(this.BoundingBox))
        this.Reset();
}

public void CheckPlayerCollision()
{
    Player player = GameWorld.Find("player") as Player;
    if (this.CollidesWith(player) && this.Visible)
        player.Die(false);
    // CURRENTLY DON'T WANT THIS TO HAPPEN BECAUSE OF HEALTH BAR
}
```

}

I just have no idea how i can get this to work, to decrease the health by 1 and eventually let the player die when there is no health left.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that one or both the lines

```
Player player = GameWorld.Find("player") as Player;
Rocket rocket = GameWorld.Find("rocket") as Rocket;
```

returns null, do that check, ensure that the gameObjects list cointains what you are looking for and that they are of the type you expect

check even if when your player Die, you remove it from the world before the code part where it gives you errors, maybe at the time of your check the player (or the rocket) has been removed from the world

Comment: How do i check the list?

Comment: set a breakpoint in your Find method, and inspect gameObjects value